# Report scrapy ResponseNeverReceived

Tags: scrapy, twisted

I would like to send status report to a database after a scrapy crawl. I already have a system in place that listens to the spider closed event and sends the reason for closing the spider to the database.

My problem is that I get a `twisted.web._newclient.ResponseNeverReceived` which ends the spider with CloseSpider('finished'). This reason is not enough for me to deduct the actual reason for failure.

How would you close the spider with a different reason when ResponseNeverReceived occurs? There doesn't seem to be any signals for that.